# How to list all available RPC and extrinsics endpoints of a node?

Tags: rpc

Is there a way to query a running (local) node and list all available RPC and/or extrinsic endpoints?

I want to create an overview for new team members and for our company, and maybe even pipe the output to a diagram tool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:9933 -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"rpc_methods","params":[],"id":1}'
```

---

The result example, extrinsic relates:

```
author_pendingExtrinsics
author_removeExtrinsic
author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic
author_submitExtrinsic
author_unwatchExtrinsic
```

Comment: Is there one for extrinsics?

Comment: Updated in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [substrate-api-sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar)
to query a running local node. By default, it provides a series of endpoints to retrieve chain information (blocks, extrinsics and storage) from nodes.
Highlighting here some extrinsics/transaction related endpoints :

`/blocks/{blockId}/extrinsics/{extrinsicIndex}`

`/node/transaction-pool`

`/transaction`

`/transaction/dry-run`

`/transaction/fee-estimate`

`/transaction/material`

but you can also check the full endpoints docs [here](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate-api-sidecar/dist/)